# Create dynamic asp.net checkbox with value attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, code-behind

How do  I add value attribute to checkbox in asp.net that is added dynamically to a panel.
Eg:

```
CheckBoxList chkIrList = new CheckBoxList();
chkIrList.DataValueField = "UserId";
chkIrList.DataTextField = "Name";
chkIrList.DataSource = DT;
chkIrList.DataBind();
```

The generated html does not holds the value field:

```
<input id="ctl26_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl26$0">
<label for="ctl26_0">XYZ</label>
```

Comment: `chkIrList.Items[0].Attributes["value"] = "xx";` Does this help?

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have inserted a checkboxlist  control in the page and then added listitem data to that checkboxlist from code behind. Now the value property is available.